# How to get angle between two vectors in 3D

Tags: c++, math

I have two objects one sphere and a cone. I want cone to always face the sphere as shown in the images.

we have constructed the cone in  local coordinate system in such a way, that the tip of the cone points upward the y-axis and the center is at the origin (0,0,0).

[image]

[image]

The angle between two  3D vectors would be

```
float fAngle = std::acos(dot(sphereVector, coneVector) / magnitude(sphereVector * magnitude(coneVector)));
```

For cone to be always facing the sphere it need to be rotated in all three axis based on the  position of the sphere but i am getting only one angle from the maths formula.

How do i calculate all the three angles for the  cone that it is  always perpendicular to the sphere.

Comment: This not really a programming question. Perhaps it is better to post in: https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You don't define what the "two 3D vectors" or the resulthing "three angles" even are. This can't be answered when that info is missing. Generally, also, do you understand what happens mathematically in that line of code you provided?

Comment: @ Ulrich Eckhardt The two 3D vectors are sphereVector and the coneVector.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The cone should be always perpendicular to the sphere.

Comment: A 3D vector has 3 numbers X, Y, Z and you can project it onto 3 planes XY, XZ and YZ. That way you can use geometry function 3 times. The formula for the angle between 2 3D vectors is irrelevant if you want to calculate 3 angles.

Comment: You don't need to resort to `euler angles rotation`. All what required to direct the cone to the sphere is a single `axis-angle rotation`. Just rotate the cone by that angle around the `axis = cross(coneVector, sphereVector)`.

Comment: @ardget That is what i am doing currently but i want the euler angles.

Comment: float angleCos = glm::dot(containerVector, pointVector);
glm::clamp(angleCos, -1.0f, -1.0f);
glm::vec3 axis = glm::cross(containerVector, pointVector);
float angle = glm::degrees(glm::acos(angleCos));
glm::mat4 rotate_matrix = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), angle, axis);

Comment: @Summit *"The two 3D vectors are sphereVector and the coneVector."* -- naming the vectors does not define them. A definition would be more like "`sphereVector` points from the origin to the center of the sphere." While this one can be guessed from the name (`coneVector` is less clear), it is ill-advisable to leave things to be guessed, especially when a clear definition is so easy to provide.

Comment: Please add missing info to your Q using the [edit] link, not in comments! Also, "cone should be always perpendicular to the sphere" again makes assumptions. Taken without context, it doesn't make sense. Asking a precise question is fundamental to getting a good answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need the vector where the cone should point to:

```
direction = center_cone - center_sphere;
```

Then, we assume, that you've constructed your cone in the local coordinate system in such a way, that the tip of the cone points upward the y-axis and the center is at the origin (0,0,0).

The axises to rotate are:

```
x_axis(1, 0, 0);
y_axis(0, 1, 0);
z_axis(0, 0, 1);
```

Now, you simply have to project the axises to the direction vector to get the 3 angles.

**Example:**

```
float angle(vec a, vec b)
{
    return acos(dot(a, b) / (magnitude(a) * magnitude(b)));
}

vec direction = normalize(center_cone - center_sphere);

float x_rot = angle(x_axis, direction);
float y_rot = angle(y_axis, direction);
float z_rot = angle(z_axis, direction);
```