# how do I maintain relative transformation b/w 2 objects after changing transformation of any one without a scenegraph?

Tags: c++, math, opengl, glm-math

Say I have 2 objects, a camera and a cube, both on XZ plane, the cube has some arbitrary rotation, and camera is facing the cube.

now if a transformation R is applied to the camera such that it has a new rotation and position.

I want to move the cube in front of the camera using transformation R1, such that in the view it looks exactly as before R was applied, meaning relative distance, rotation and scale b/w the 2 objects remain same after both R and R1.

Following image gives a gist of the problem.

[image]

Assume that there's no scenegraph that we can use.
I've posed the problem mainly in 2D but I'm trying to solve it in 3D, so rotations can have all yaw, pitch and roll, and translations can be anywhere in 3D space.

EDIT:

I forgot to add what I have done so far.

I figured out how to maintain relative distance b/w camera and cube, I can project cube's position to get world to screen point, then unproject the screen point in new camera position to get new world position.

However for rotation, I have tried this

- I thought I can apply same rotation as R in R1, this didn't work, it appears to work if rotation happens only in one axis, if rotation happens in more than one axes, it does not work.
- I thought I can take delta rotation b/w camera and cube, and simply apply camera's rotation to the cube and then multiply delta rotation, this also didn't work

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74427737/how-to-get-angle-between-two-vectors-in-3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let M and V be the model and view matrices before you move the camera, M2 and V2 be the matrices after you move the camera. To be clear: model matrix transforms the coordinates from object local coordinates into world coordinates; a view matrix transforms from world coordinates into clip-space camera coordinates. Consequently `V*M*p` transforms the position `p` into clip-space.

For the position on the screen to stay constant, we need `V*M*p = V2*M2*p` to be true for all `p` (that's assuming that the FOV doesn't change). Therefore `V*M = V2*M2`, or

```
M2 = inverse(V2)*V*M
```

If you apply the camera transformation on the right (`V2 = V*R`) then the above expression for `M2` can be simplified:

```
M2 = inverse(R)*M
```

(that is you apply `inverse(R)` on the left of the model matrix to compensate).

---

Alternatively, ask yourself if you really need to keep the object coordinates in the world reference frame. It may be easier to *not* to apply the view matrix when rendering that object at all; that would effectively keep it relative to the camera at all times without any additional tweaks. That would have better numerical stability too.

Comment: Actually I was trying to make an object move with the camera, and I did something very similar to this. Problem was I couldn't figure out how to detach the object from the camera once done and place it in the world seamlessly. It turned out the whole issue was due to messy implementation caused by using 2 different math libraries in Java and c++ levels, Matrix4f and glm